# Is the MediaTypeHeaderValue class thread-safe?

Tags: c#, thread-safety

Tell me the [MediaTypeHeaderValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.headers.mediatypeheadervalue?view=net-5.0) class is thread-safe? Conditionally, I can use it in this way:

```cs
public class MyClass 
{
    // example
    private static readonly MediaTypeHeaderValue mediaType 
        = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/octet-stream");

    // the method can be called from different threads
    public void Execute() 
    {
        // Use MediaTypeHeaderValue like
        // HttpRequestMessage request = ...
        // ...
        // request.Content.Headers.ContentType = mediaType; // <---
        // ...
    }
}
```

To avoid creating an instance every time, thereby reducing the load on the GC ?

Comment: "thereby reducing the load on the GC" -- generally the allocations made by the rest of your app will drastically outweigh the overhead of creating an instance of this class when you need it. Have you profiled and found that you are allocating too many of these? You posted a similar question about x509Certificate2. Is it really that important that you conserve all the allocations? In other words is memory usage by your application critical and it's been proven that reduction in the number of such objects will help your cause? Did you race your horses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends what you do with it. If you just read it, like you're showing in the code comments, then it should be OK. If you start mutating the header (for instance by changing the value of the `MediaType` property), then all bets are off.

Answer (score 1):

In general the axiom is: thread-safety is explicit, non-thread-safety is implied. This means that either the documentation states explicitly that a class is thread-safe, or makes no such statement, in which case you should assume that the class is not thread-safe. Non-thread-safety means that accessing the members of the class from multiple threads concurrently results to undefined behavior. Undefined behavior means that "anything" can happen, and if you don't like it you won't be able to file a bug report, because whatever happens will not be considered a bug by the manufacturer of the class.